# What is the difference between these data types?

Tags: c++, types, integer, int, unsigned

In C++, what is the difference between short int, unsigned int, signed int, and int? What are there applications? When do you use short int, unsigned int, etc. ?

Comment: I can't downvote this hard enough -- "this question does not show any research effort."

Comment: It's now 2016. Looking back to this post, I don't know why I asked this question! Stupid me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look! You tell me!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout << "min_int = " << numeric_limits<int>::min() << endl;
    cout << "max_int = " << numeric_limits<int>::max() << endl;

    cout << "min_unsigned_int = " << numeric_limits<unsigned int>::min() << endl;
    cout << "max_unsigned_int = " << numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() << endl;

    cout << "min_short = " << numeric_limits<short>::min() << endl;
    cout << "max_short = " << numeric_limits<short>::max() << endl;

    cout << "min_unsigned_short = " << numeric_limits<unsigned short>::min() << endl;
    cout << "max_unsigned_short = " << numeric_limits<unsigned short>::max() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The best answer to 90% of programming questions: let's try it and see!

Comment: The problem I have with this is that you may fall into the trap in which you think these are the only values you'll ever have without understanding that these limits may change.

Comment: James is correct.  The sizes that you see will depend upon your architecture, but one thing is certain, unsigned variables can not be negative, an int is always longer than a short, and a long is always longer than an int.

Comment: It's now 2016. Looking back to this post, I don't know why I asked this question! Stupid me

Comment: @Trevor Hickey I could have researched before even asking this you know. Hahaha

Answer (score 1):

In most cases int is what you want, if you are going to be strictly working with non negative numbers unsigned is good. But often standard library function return negative values for errors.

Short is primarily used for small values in larger data structures as a memory optimization, or for interfacing with network or file formats.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a function that accepts only positive numbers, which might be done to restrict others from passing it negative values or from freeing your function from having to check the sign of the values passed, you could use an unsigned int. Of course this doesn't stop anybody from casting a negative int to an unsigned int. This will just results in your function interpreting it as a huge number (since the most significant bit will be 1 to represent the previously negative number) but then that's the fault of the person casting that value.